# JavaScript - Can I make each image in an array a unique link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, hyperlink

I'm very new to JavaScript, and was hoping for some help.
I'm trying to build a sliding banner, that has 5 different pictures displayed and rotated simultaneously. I've got that working with 5 versions of this code:

```
<body onLoad="swapImage2();"/>      <!--Linked with jquery-->

       <script language="JavaScript"> 
var k = 0; var path2 = new Array(); 

// LIST OF IMAGES 
path2[0] = "pics/prime/1r.png"; 
path2[1] = "pics/prime/2r.png"; 
path2[2] = "pics/prime/3r.png"; 
path2[3] = "pics/prime/4r.png";

function swapImage2() 
{ 
document.slider.src = path2[k]; 
if(k < path2.length - 1) k++; 
else k = 0; 
setTimeout("swapImage2()",6000); 
} 
</script> 
<img class="small_banner" name="slider"/> <!-- This is where the image is displayed-->
```

So the img tags is where the array item is displayed. I need each image in all 5 arrays to have it's own link to various pages in my site. 
To clarify:

```
<a href="#"><img class="small_banner" name="slider"/></a>
```

won't work, since that makes the entire display area one link, where I need pics/prime/1r.png (2r,3r,4r) to each be their own link.

Here's the complete code as I'm using it:http:http://jsfiddle.net/BeaverKing/3wR5f/1/

I know I'm most likely missing something obvious, or perhaps I'm just using the wrong script for the job. If so, could someone suggest a better script?

EDIT:

I've spent the last week looking for a slider that does the job without success. I've tried using the bootstrap carousel, I've tried CarouFredSel, OwlCarousel, TimothySlider, WoW-Slider, CarouselEngine, CircularContentCarousel. None of these work stylistically with what I want, and when I tried to run multiple instances of the script, I was getting conflicts causing the code to break. I'm really not good enough to identify the conflicts in code, so I tried to write one myself. I'm posting my question here as a last resort.

Comment: There’s plenty of slider scripts out there, so please go and find one yourself.

Comment: I have tried. I've spent the last week looking for one that does the job without success. I've tried using the bootstrap carousel, I've tried CarouFredSel, OwlCarousel, TimothySlider, WoW-Slider, CarouselEngine, CircularContentCarousel. None of these work stylistically with what I want, and when I tried to run multiple instances of the script, I was getting conflicts causing the code to break. I'm really not good enough to identify the conflicts in code, so I tried to write one myself. I'm posting my question here as a last resort.

Comment: When you tried, for instance, the Bootstrap carousel what didn't work for you? If within each `<div class="item">` you had a link surrounding an image wouldn't that have done what you are trying to do?

Comment: I can get each image in the bootstrap slider to be a clickable link, that wasn't the issue. The problem was running the slider twice. When I link two of the same slider, only the first one works. I tried using one slider to do the job, but I was unable to style it how I wanted. I need a 750px wide by 200px high banner, and then right next to it I need 4 250px wide by 50px high banners, and each of them needs to scroll every 6 seconds. When I tried CarouFredSel, it caused a conflict with a randomise slider I'm using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i undestand right, you need add `id` attribute to `a` tag and in swap function set `href` for it. something like that:

```
<a href="#" id='link_for_img'><img class="small_banner" name="slider"/></a>
```

and script

```
// LIST OF IMAGES WITH PATHS
path2[0] = { img:"pics/prime/1r.png", link: 'pics/prime/1r.png'};
path2[1] = { img:"pics/prime/2r.png", link: 'pics/prime/2r.png'};
path2[2] = { img:"pics/prime/3r.png", link: 'pics/prime/3r.png'};
path2[3] = { img:"pics/prime/4r.png", link: 'pics/prime/4r.png'};

function swapImage2() 
{ 
    document.slider.src = path2[k].img; 
    document.getElementById('link_for_img').href = path2[k].link;
    if(k < path2.length - 1) k++; 
    else k = 0; 
    setTimeout(swapImage2,6000); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bud, but alas it did not work. It now only displays the first image in the set, and isn't going to the link, but is instead linking to #

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function - if I'm reading this correctly, it's saying that swapImage2() is not defined

Comment: @BeaverKing it was typo in `getElementById` try again :-)

Comment: You sir are a ROCKSTAR! It's working like an absolute charm. Thank you so much for the assist bro :-)